# Realm React native sorted order

Tags: sorting, react-native, realm

Basically I have a MessageSchema with a date property, on my app I need to query all the messages stored on the database and be able to sort them by their date to display them on a ListView, I do the query as follows:

```
return realm.objects("Message").sorted('date');
```

This works, but only one way, the messages are sorted on ascending order only, I haven't found a way to do it on descending order and the docs of the react native only show one example:

```
let hondas = realm.objects('Car').filtered('make = "Honda"');
// Sort Hondas by mileage
let sortedHondas = hondas.sorted('miles');
```

Any advice is welcome.

Versions:

```
react-native: "0.40.0"
realm js: "1.0.2"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
return realm.objects("Message").sorted('date', true);
```

Looking at the source code you can see that the sorted method expects
a descriptor and a Boolean named reverse, that it is set as false unless
you change it, so the code above just reverses the order.